# Jquery - Getting 3 random array elements without crossover

Tags: jquery, arrays

I'm creating an application. For part of it I need to be able to pull 3 random array elements without the same 3 repeating at all in the 1 function

example:

```
var arr = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10]
$("#button").click(function()
{
    rand = Math.floor((Math.random() * arr.length));
    $("text1").text(arr[rand]);
    rand = Math.floor((Math.random() * arr.length));
    $("text2").text(arr[rand]);
    rand = Math.floor((Math.random() * arr.length));
    $("text3").text(arr[rand]);
})
```

I've repeated the randomizer 3 times because if I don't the number stays the same. The issue with this is that the random number generator could pull up the same number more than once. Is there a way to avoid this happening?

If this is a dupe question, I'm sorry but it didn't show up in the suggested questions.

EDIT: HTML Added per request

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-role="page" id="menu">
            <div data-role="header">
                <div data-role="navbar">
                    <p><h2 align="center">App Name</h2></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div data-role="content">
                <div>
                    <h1 style="font-size:50px" align="center" id="name"></h1>
                </div>
                <div style="padding-top:30px">
                    <h1 align="center" id="q"></h1>
                </div>
                <div style="padding-top:50px">
                    <p align="center"><a style="font-size:22px" id="text1"></a></p>
                    <p align="center"><a style="font-size:22px" id="text2"></a></p>
                    <p align="center"><a style="font-size:22px" id="text3"></a></p>
                </div>
                <div style="padding-top:50px">
                    <h3 align="center" id="counter"></h3>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
                <div data-role="navbar">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a id="t">Restart</a></li>
                        <li><a id="qu">Quit</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html
```

Comment: make a duplicate of the array each time the function is called, and for each random number remove the result from the array and perform the next random on the remaining elements.

Comment: Something like splice? I'm using that for other arrays, the thing is that this needs to be repeated 10 times with roughly 25 - 30 total array elements. I was hoping it would just be as simple as just using an if statement. But ill give it a go. Thanks

Comment: can you please provide the porject html I want to test it ^_^ !

Comment: The important html with this is really just 3 text boxes with the id's as they are. I'll add it in though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can create a array of radmoize value

like this

```
var temp=[];

while(temp.length<3){
  rand = Math.floor((Math.random() * arr.length));
  if(temp.indexOf(arr[rand])<0){
    temp.push(arr[rand])
  }
}
```

then add the randomize value to your view

```
$("text1").text(temp[0]);
$("text2").text(temp[1]);
$("text3").text(temp[2]);
```

<kbd>**[`DEMO`](https://jsfiddle.net/aiubian/1usadu34/)**</kbd>

You are also missing " at the end of your array (that's may be typo)

```
var arr = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10]
                                                 ^
                                                here
```

Comment: I'll check it out, I was just about to try an if statement to compare the previous text() inputs to the next random number and see if that worked.

Comment: @John you check the demo that i provided in my answer

Comment: Using that example, it just produced the same 3 numbers.

Comment: Ok, the jsfiddle seems to work, must have done something wrong on my end.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a copy of the array, and remove elements as they are randomly chosen:

```
var arr = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10"]; // fix end here

$("#button").click(function() {
    var arr2 = arr.slice(0); // clone array
    for (var i = 1; i < 4; i++) { // loop to avoid code duplication
        rand = Math.floor((Math.random() * arr2.length));
        $("text" + i).text(arr2[rand]);
        arr2.splice(rand, 1); // remove selected element
    };
});
```

Comment: @John i personally think that in terms of performance, this answer is much better. the method in the other answer only checks if the randomly selected value already exists in the temporary array, and if the number of random elements that you need to retrieve gets close to the number of elements in the original array, that function can run hundreds more iterations. while this one ensures that there are only as many cycles as the required number of elements.